# How to write a SQLite SELECT query with WHERE clause to get both matched and unmatched values

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to write a query in SQLite passing multiple values to WHERE clause where the returned results contain both the matched and unmatched values.

I have a table named `songs` with the following columns:
`song_id`, `song_title`, `artist_name`

I want to pass on an array of song titles to see if they exist in the table or not. If they exist, the returned list should contain both `song_title` and `artist_name` but if some titles don't exist, only the given title is returned.

For example, if following values exist in the table:

1, 'song1', 'artist1'

2, 'song2', 'artist1'

3, 'song3', 'artist2'

4, 'song4', 'artist1'

and I write the following query statement:

`SELECT song_title, artist_name FROM songs WHERE song_title IN ('song1', 'song2', 'song5');`

What it returns is as follows:

'song1', 'artist1'

'song2', 'artist1'

What I want is as follows:

'song1', 'artist1'

'song2', 'artist1'

'song5'

So, in a sense, I want all the values in the given array to be returned back with artist name against those that exist in the table. It is a reverse sort of query but I am unable to figure out how to write it.

Any help would be a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do here would be to maintain a table of all songs.  As an example, I inline this information below in a subquery:

```
SELECT t.song_title, s.artist_name
FROM
(
    SELECT 'song1' AS song_title UNION ALL
    SELECT 'song2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'song3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'song4' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'song5'
) t
LEFT JOIN songs s
    ON t.song_title = s.song_title
WHERE
    t.song_title IN ('song1', 'song2', 'song5');
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, the passed on values in my case will be unknown. Sorry if the impression from my example was the other way around.

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan I have answered your question.

Comment: Won't it be impossible to write such a query if the passed on values are large in number, lets say 100 or more?

Comment: Not at all, assuming you don't exceed the number of items which may appear in a `WHERE IN` clause.

Comment: See its a query with unknown number of values that will be passed on. Sometimes, the values will be 2, sometimes 100 etc. How to make the statement dynamic to cater whatever number of values are passed on.

Comment: My answer already works for all your cases.  Did you read my actual answer?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm unable to get the subquery part of your answer. I just can't understand why we have to write all the values using SELECT in the subquery. If there are 100 values, we will write all the 100 values in subquery?

Comment: Oh...yes, typically you would have to write those values, or pass them in, or else store them in a table of some kind.

Comment: Ok I intend to use this solution in an Android application that uses Room library and I intend to pass those multiple values using a `String[]`. So, should I first store them all in a table and then compare this newly written table with the existing `songs` table to get the results? Seems like a very long procedure.

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan You are really asking for several things here.  I answered your original question, which was how to write a query to report the output you expect, given a fixed set of songs in the `WHERE` clause.  If you also need help with the Room API, then you should open a new question.

Comment: new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719529/is-there-a-way-to-compare-a-list-of-values-with-a-sqlite-table

Answer (score 0):

You can do a left join on self. Something like this:

```
SELECT a.song_title, a.artist_name 
  FROM songs a left join 
    songs b on a.song_id = b.song_id
  WHERE a.song_title IN ('song1', 'song2', 'song5');
```

Comment: Sorry, it ain't working. It still doesn't return 'song5'.