# Is there a way to compare a list of values with a SQLite table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I need this solution for my Android app that uses Room library for persisting data. I need to implement a solution where a list of string values is passed on by the user, it is compared with the data in the table and then returned back with both matched and unmatched results.

So, in a sense I want all the string values given by the user returned back no matter if they got matched with the table values or not. The matched values however would have more data from the table and unmatched values would be just values.

For example, I have a `tasks` table having columns namely `task_id`, `task_title`, `task_status`. This table has the following data:

1, 'Task 1', 'In process'

2, 'Task 2', 'On hold'

3, 'Task 3', 'Completed'

4, 'Task 4', 'In process'

Now user passes on a list of values to see if there is any data available against any of these or not. If there is a match, they would like to be presented with the status of that task.
This list is passed in the form of a `String[]` and can contain any values and any number of values. Let us suppose that the string array is as follows:

`{'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 5'}`

What sort of a query would be required that returns the following results:

'Task 2', 'On hold'

'Task 3', 'Completed'

'Task 5', Not available (or any other or no message)

So, I need all of the values passes on through the string array returned with data against those that got matched and no data (or a message) against the ones that didn't match.

What I have already tried are queries in the following form:

`@Query("SELECT task_title, task_status FROM tasks WHERE task_title IN (:values)")
LiveData<List<Task>> getTasks(String[] values);`

It would return the following as per above example:

'Task 2', 'On hold'

'Task 3', 'Completed'

It doesn't return the unmatched value 'Task 5' which actually is required to be returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a straight `SELECT`. There is no straightforward (read: simple) way to accomplish this in sqlite. The `:values` is an "unknown" to sqlite. Have you considered adding the unmatched results to the returned object, based on the difference between the sql result and the input values?

If  [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_json_function) is installed, you might try something like this:

```
SELECT value,  
CASE when t.task_status is null then "NOT FOUND" else t.task_status END status
FROM json_each(json_array(:values))
LEFT join tasks t on t.task_title = value
```

Another option might be a table that holds each input value in a row, so the same JOIN strategy can be applied.

The bottom line is the input list must be "tokenized" into individual elements so the status of each can be determined.

Comment: :values...I've fixed the code by editing the question. Yes I'm now considering adding the unmatched results to the SQL results manually. And I'm also considering first adding all the input values to a temporary table and then getting the results by using a JOIN. Contents of such table would be removed after each such query. Thanks for taking time to reply!